# Powepoint VBA. Slide startup event

Tags: vba, slideshow, powerpoint

I need help. Please explain to me if i can add a load event to my slides (using **VBA**). Example: When i load slide 3, a macro to be executed.

Is that possible? If yes, how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: It is possible according to msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff746018.aspx Give it a try and let us now how it goes! :) (For a list of all events supported, see http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/events_version.html)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this to happen in slideshow view or in normal editing view?

If in slide show view, the simplest thing might be to add your own navigation buttons that trigger a macro like:

```
Sub NextSlide()

    ' go to the next slide
    ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide (SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide(SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.SlideIndex))

    ' and insert whatever code you like here:

End Sub
```